# Sql create a view X_myview where X is given into a function(X text) which creates the view

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-view, sql-function

Trying to create a function that given the name of a table will create a function with the table name concatenated  to _myView

eg if the name of the  table is students the function will create a view called students_myView

Here's what I have so far.

```
create or replace function skyline_naive(tableName text)
as $$
declare
name text;

begin
name:= $1;
create or replace view name_myView as select * from name;

end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic command in PLPgSQL must be executed as a string with [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) statement.

To make it work, you should write it like this:

```
create or replace function skyline_naive(tableName text) 
  returns void as $$
begin
  execute format('create or replace view %1$s_myView as select * from %1$s;', tableName)
  return;
end;
$$ language
  plpgsql;
```